# Validate/extract US Phone numbers with .net regular expression out of mixed character value

Tags: .net, regex, phone-number

I need a regular expression for .net that can extract a phone number from a mixed character value, such as the following examples:

> yyy1-555-555-5555yyy1
>   yyy555-555-5555yyy1
>   yyy1(555)555-5555yyy1
>   yyy5555555555yyy1
>   yyy1-(555)-555-5555yyy1
>   yyy1(555)-555-5555yyy1
>   yyy(555)555-5555yyy1

The pattern `^\+?([0-9]+[ -]?){5,}[0-9]+$` seems very basic and works fairly well but it isn't working with all the different ways a phone number can be presented as shown above.

I am very new to regular expressions, and this seems like it may be a lot to ask but I would appreciate the help if it's relatively easy for someone to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the following regex:

```
(?:1-?)?\(?\d{3}\)?[-.]?\s*\d{3}[-.]?\s*\d{4}
```

Or with "boundaries":

```
(?<!\d)(?:1-?)?\(?\d{3}\)?[-.]?\s*\d{3}[-.]?\s*\d{4}(?!\d)
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3A1-%3F)%3F%5C(%3F%5Cd%7B3%7D%5C)%3F%5B-.%5D%3F%5Cs*%5Cd%7B3%7D%5B-.%5D%3F%5Cs*%5Cd%7B4%7D&i=yyy1-555-555-5555yyy1%0D%0Ayyy555-555-5555yyy1%0D%0Ayyy1(555)555-5555yyy1%0D%0Ayyy5555555555yyy1%0D%0Ayyy1-(555)-555-5555yyy1%0D%0Ayyy1(555)-555-5555yyy1%0D%0Ayyy(555)555-5555yyy1)

The regex explanation:

- `(?:1-?)?` - an optional (1 or zero) sequence of `1` and an optional hyphen
- `\(?\d{3}\)?` - 3 digit sequence optionally enclosed with `(...)`
- `[-.]?` - an optional separator (either `-` or `.`, add more if necessary)
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespace (if you need to exclude line breaks, use `\p{Zs}`)
- `\d{3}` - 3 digit sequence
- `[-.]?` - 1 or 0 separators
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespace
- `\d{4}` - 4 digit sequence.

The look-arounds, `(?<!\d)` and `(?!\d)`, only allow a match if the whole pattern is not enclosed with digits.